# laravel with codeception unitTesting : can't check relation

Tags: php, laravel-5, relation, codeception

I want to unittest `hasMany` `belongsTo`&more method.

## environment

- laravel 5.0.33
- codeception 2.0.16

example
`app/User.php`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Users', 'name', 'user');
}
```

what would be a good way to do it?